# How Can I setup an election system using Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: web-part

We would like to run a college election on Sharepoint. Is that possible? I can't find a webpart anywhere for this.

Comment: Have you looked at the survey app (or list - not sure which version of SharePoint you're using)? At a basic level, you can mask user names in results (so it's anonymous) and enforce that users can only answer (vote) once. What features are you looking for, specifically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Survey List to run a College elections.

**Step 1: Ensure the 'Team Collaboration Lists' Features is activated.**

As an administrator, navigate to 'Site Settings' -> 'Site Features'. Scroll down the list and ensure that the 'team collaboration lists' feature says 'Active'. If it doesn't click 'Activate'. If you aren't an administrator, you need to find one to get them to activate this feature. (It usually is though on collaboration / team sites).

**Step 2 : Create a new Survey list from the 'create' menu.**

Now that the relevant feature is activated, you should now be able to navigate to the 'Create' menu which is accessible from the 'view all site content' menu item. Once on the menu select 'Survey' list and call the list 'Training Survey'.

**Step 3 : Add Name of candidates to your survey List**

It's time to add candidates, so lets ask away!

- RAMBO
- PETER
- JOHN

**Step 4 : Configure your survey**

As this stage you may be totally happy with the survey and it's ready to go! however, there may be a few things you want to do from here.

**Step 5 :Advanced Settings**

One final groups of settings that you may want to make is around who can edit and view the answers when they are input. This can be quite important if you do not want a user who has responded to be able to see all the other users answers. The settings below illustrate this. You may also want to turn of search crawling if you don't want the answers to appear in search results.

**Step 6 :Add Survey Webpart to page**

Add survey list webpart to the page where voting would be done by user say Home Page.

*Done...!!!*